# Angular JS factory in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, controller, factory

Have a trouble with calling ASP.NET MVC Controller Action Methods from angular js factory.

```
var HomeModule = angular.module('HomeModule', []);

HomeModule.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {  

});
```

This is my angular JS controller.

```
<div ng-app="HomeModule" class="row">
<div ng-controller="HomeController" class="row">

</div>
```

Index.cshtml part of code looks like this.
When I am trying to bind some $scope propetry from controller - is works. Please help me create factory like this to call my ASP.NET Controller Methods. All my solutions give's me errors in console.

```
someControllerApp.factory('someFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {

var service = {
    GetSomeData: function () {
        return $http.post('/Some/SomeMethod');
    },
};
return service;
}]);
```

Error:

```
angular.js:14324 TypeError: someFactory.GetSomeData(...).success is not a function
at ChildScope.$scope.GetData (HomeController.js:7)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:1), <anonymous>:4:141)
at callback (angular.js:26673)
at ChildScope.$eval (angular.js:17958)
at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:18058)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:26678)
at defaultHandlerWrapper (angular.js:3613)
at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (angular.js:3601)
```

When Controller:

```
    var HomeModule = angular.module('HomeModule', []);

HomeModule.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, someFactory) {  

    $scope.GetData = function () {

        someFactory.GetSomeData().success(function (data) {
            if (data.isSuccess) {
                $scope.Address = data;
            } else {
                window.location.assign("/Error/Error500");
            }
        });
    };

});


HomeModule.factory('someFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var service = {
        GetSomeData: function () {
            return $http.post('/Home/GetUserData');
        }
    };
    return service;
    }]);
```

Comment: What are the errors in the console?

Comment: edited post with error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  You need to define your factory as part of you angular module.  Then you can inject your factory into your controller and use it.  Like this:

```
var HomeModule = angular.module('HomeModule', []);

HomeModule.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'someFactory', function($scope, someFactory) {
  someFactory.GetSomeData().then(function(result) {
    $scope.data = result.data;
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}]);

HomeModule.factory('someFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
  var service = {
    GetSomeData: function() {
      return $http.post('/Some/SomeMethod');
    },
  };
  return service;
}]);
```

Here's a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/gKVH94mtMli4yqps1qnM?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! It works with base-types return methods and ActionResult methods too.